# How do I auto-populate desired fields in a new object form with triggers after clicking on "Save & New" button?

Tags: salesforce-lightning, apex-trigger

I'm fairly new to Salesforce and I'm trying to auto-populate a couple of custom fields in an object when creating a new one when I click on "Save & New" to make the process more userfriendly.

For example, the first time I'll fill in a serial number and the corresponding date, and the rest of the data.
When I click on "Save & New", I want the exact serial number and date pre-filled in the new object form, seeing that otherwise, it will take too much time.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is write a custom lightning component (LWC) to replace the standard "New" button and then add your logic when you click on "Save & New" to relaunch with pre-filled values.